# How can get ec2 instance ip from instance id in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using ansible cloudformation to create stack with 20 instances.
Now in the ansible output i can only see the instance ids.

Now after the stack is created i want to connect to them and configure it but i am not sure how can get thos ips or hostnames from instance id.

cloudformation output is like this

```
    {
        "last_updated_time": null,
        "logical_resource_id": "test2",
        "physical_resource_id": "i-24tf97306",
        "resource_type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "status": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
        "status_reason": null
    },
    {
        "last_updated_time": null,
        "logical_resource_id": "test1",
        "physical_resource_id": "i-6533184348",
        "resource_type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "status": "CREATE_COMPLETE",
        "status_reason": null
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ec2_remote_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) module is your friend here.

Comment: In the current version ec2_remote_facts does not provide public, does it?https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/1509

Comment: yes, you may apply fix locally or use `public_dns_name`

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve [instance meta data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) when Ansible runs on the instance e.g.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
ec2-aa-bb-cc-ddd.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

where `aa-bb-cc-ddd` represents your IP and the full string represents the hostname.

You're using Ansible so you could use Ansible's `get_url` module: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/get_url_module.html to perform the HTTP request.

Comment: but that is only accessible from inside instance not from ansible host